# Add to OnFocus codebehind without deleting current OnFocus

Tags: c#, asp.net, focus, onfocus

I'm developing an ASP.NET page with c# on the backend.

I have some javascript to keep track of where the last focus was before postback, and setting it after postback. However, if the field getting focus is a password field, I need to clear the input when the control gets focus.

I have added this like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
    TextBox.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.value=''");
    }
}
```

but now it overrides my JavaScript, so when I click the next textbox the focus is lost.

Can I add the lines after each other in some way? Like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPassword" runat="server" TextMode="password" onfocus="try{document.getElementById(&#39;__LASTFOCUS&#39;).value=this.id} catch(e) {} + this.value=''" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I know it cannot be done with a `+`, but is there some way to do this?

Comment: you actually want the password field to lose content only on first focus it it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out by calling it by the id of my textbox, generated by asp.net.

```
if(document.getElementById('REQUEST_LASTFOCUS') == document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBoxAdgangskode')) 
                    {
                        document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBoxAdgangskode').value = '';
                    }
```

I dont know if this is a "good pratice" to call the id directly, but i could not get the other to work.

Answer (score 0):

instead doing this (which will clear the value always when the control has focus) can't you clear it from code behind like below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
      TextBox.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i use an updatepanel around the textbox(textbox=password), so i only have to update that content of the page instead of a full postback. So im using asyncpostbacktrigger.
You cannot set TextBox.Text on a textbox which has textmode="password".
I have tried to add it in the javascript instead, but doesnt really work. Im not good at javascript, and that properly where the problem  is.
Pastbin link(Cause im not allowed to post so many chars):
http://pastebin.com/TLYe9rSd

Answer (score 0):

You should create a JavaScript function to handle applying the focus:

```
applyFocus = function(ctrl, clearOnFocus) {
    if (clearOnFocus){
        ctrl.value = "";
    }
    ctrl.focus();
}
```

And you can implement it like this:

```
<asp:TextBox Id="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" onfocus="applyFocus(this, true);" ...>
```

Comment: That looks good James, but i allready have a javascript to handle the last focus, which adds itself to every control on my page. So cant i put something like this in the javascript aswell:

if(document.getElementById('REQUEST_LASTFOCUS') == document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxAdgangskode.clientID%>') 
{
  document.getElementById('TextBoxAdgangskode').value = "";
}

The other javascript handles the REQUEST_LASTFOCUS, so im not really sure what im missing in the if.

Comment: Okay so i found out that im really too used to intellisense :P I there was missing a ')' in the if statement and adding the .clientid where i add the value aswell.
But it is still not working. Here is the code for how the script looks like now:
http://pastebin.com/H9rgykPm

And again dont think about how i get REQUEST_LASTFOCUS, that is working perfectly. Im just interested in getting the if staments working :)